# Explain about Route Constraint Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to constraint rails to have multiple version of api routes. Then i read a tutorial using constraint class.

route.rb

```rb
require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :users, only: [:create, :show]
    end

    scope module: :v2, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 2) do
      resources :users, only: [:create, :show]
    end
  end
end
```

api_constraint

```rb
class ApiConstraints
  def initialize(options)
    @version = options[:version]
    @default = options[:default]
  end

  def matches?(req)
    req.headers['Accept'].include?("application/vnd.shop.becker.v#{@version}") || @default
  end
end
```

And i have multiple users_controller on different module folder

users_controller.rb (module v1)

```rb
module Api
  module V1
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def show
        render json: {hello: 'false'}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb (module v2)

```rb
module Api
  module V2
    class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def show
        render json: { hello: 'true'}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

my default version is 1, (because default is true in route file), then i expect if i dont send header 'Accept' then it will call my users_controller module V1 and my result is fine.

but if send using header 'Accept' equal to application/vnd.shop.becker.v2. It still call my users_controller.rb in module v1.

Can somebody help me to explain how constraint and the class ApiConstraints work on routes.rb?
and why if i send Accept to equal application/vnd.shop.becker.v2 is still call my module v1?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set up correctly everything fine, just have to change the order of the v1 and v2 blocks.

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    scope module: :v2, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 2) do
      resources :users, only: [:create, :show]
    end

    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      resources :users, only: [:create, :show]
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is related with the order of the routes and the constraints together. With the default flag true, v1 constraint always matches the request, so it tries to match the routes defined in the v1 block and if there is any then the request is routed there. That's why setting the v2 header landed in the v1 users controller.

Comment: can you explain what happen in rails when it call api_constraint class?

Comment: The router's basic behaviour is to go over the entries in order and call the action when there's a match. In your original snippet, it takes the v1 scope, sees there's a constraint and calls that with the request. The constraint returns true as it's marked default, hence the router checks the routes inside the v1 scope. There is a match for `/users/1` so it calls v1 users controller. If you remove the default flag, it works also perfectly, but you loose defaulting to v1. [Check out the docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) Is that what you were curious about?